# Chrome CSS background image appears with white area

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, background

I have a mysterious (at least for me) css background image problem, that I run into only with Google Chrome. I have found similar topics, but unlike those, here no Javascript, JQuery or anything else is involved, it is pure CSS. It's just not working as it should.

If you open up the page www.bodrogietterem.hu, the background image should be below the entire content area (as it is in other browsers). In Chrome a horizontal and vertical white area is appearing.

Once you start scrolling, the background image appears all okay, and it stays there from then on. Similarly, when you open the dev tool with inspect element, the background image is immediately there, and stays there, too.

this is the pertaining css:

```
body.page-node-1  div#main{
background:#FFFFFF url('/sites/all/themes/bodrogietterem/images/bodrogi_bodrogi.jpg') bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:50% 135px;
padding-bottom:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

and attaching two screengrabs on how it looks like, and how it should look like (well, I'm not allowed to attach these, as a new user, but have a look here:

http://www.bodrogietterem.hu/chrome_issue.JPG

and here

http://www.bodrogietterem.hu/should_look_like.JPG

It happens on sub-pages, too, but I think the root of the problem must be the same.

I'm using Vista, with up to date Chrome (20.0.1132.57), and up to date other browsers. btw, the second screenshot was taken in Chrome, too, but after opening the dev tool

many thanks for your kind help,
bests,
Zsolt

Comment: The screenshots produce a 400 bad request error. I opened your page in Firefox, Chrome and IE and they all look the same: The scroll doesn't work at all for me.

Comment: Hi David, the scroll was not working because I was messing around with the css at that very moment :-) it should be ok now

Comment: Also, I fixed the screenshot URLs, uploaded them to my server

Comment: I've seen bugs similar to this in Chrome due to addons such as BitTorrent tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Chrome is 21.0... so try updating chrome browser and see if it appears ok in the latest version. The screenshots lead to a 404 error page, so try uploading the screenshots again.

I also checked the page in IE7, IE8, IE9 the page looks good in all 3, IE7 however shows a horizontal scrollbar at bottom but the background image looks ok.

Comment: Hi Raj, I've run the installer at https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/, but I got the same version as before (20.0.1132.57)

the About menu also says that the browser is up to date

where do you get v21 from?

David, the scroll was not working because I was messing around on the site with css - it should be all ok now

any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your page looks fine in Chrome in windows 7 (Chrome 20.0.1132.57)

I have had problems in the past where various toolbars / addons that have been installed interfere with the CSS on a page quite significantly rendering Chrome to appear to bug out in isolated incidents. Try running chrome with no addons / plgins installed and see if it fixes your problem.

One observation on your CSS: `#content` contains floated elements that aren't cleared. I dont think that's the problem here but could be mixed with the above possibly.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the hint, but unfortunately it did not work for me. I don't have a BitTorrent tool bar, and after disabling every extension I had, the problem still persisted. Anyway, I managed to resolve the problem (see my answer below), although still unsure what caused it in the first place. Thanks again, Zsolt

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helpful thoughts, I finally managed to resolve the problem.

While fiddling around, I measured the height of the white area, and it turned out to be 135px (which is exactly the top position of the background in the CSS above). So I decided that for whatever reason, that attribute was causing the problem, and I was right.

as a quick and dirty solution, I added 135px of white area to the top of the background image, and set the background-position property's top to 0px - which immediately fixed the issue.

as for the vertical white area, it was resolved by binding the background image to the #main-wrapper div instead of the #main  div (it is a Drupal 7 build). Again, I don't exactly know why, but it fixed the problem instantly.

I love, how the web should be precise and logical, and it still stays random and ad hoc at times

thanks again for your time and effort, bests,
Zsolt

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with two pages of http://www.stoerbeton.nl but I think I solved it after reading your above posts and some thinking.

The problem was probably in the general background: url; attribute and loading of the website css. I replaced all general background: #222222 url repeat etc.; for background-image:; , background-repeat:; and background-color:; etc.

Please let me know if your website works after editing your css. I'm still testing.

Greets, aquaster.nl